# When should i use logger.error and logger.info

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, slf4j

I have a doubt about logging error messages and information messages in my project. I have seen logging the exception messages in catch block using logger.info in my project by other developers. As per me it should be logger.error, as we are logging the error messages.

Can you please clarify my doubt?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question has no objectively true answer. It is a matter of opinion or conventions in the project that you are working on. Discuss it with your coworkers.

Comment: Voting to close, once the answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Info should be : Informational statements concerning program state, representing program events or behavior tracking. So that even a layman by reading the logs can make out the transition. Error should be  statements that describe non-fatal errors in the application; this level is used quite often for logging handled exceptions, so anything in the catch block can be logged as error and also any validations if any that fail

Answer (score 1):

if you use code quality management tool like sonarcube you will see that catched exceptions must be rethrown or logged with LOG.error. I recommend you and your team to use [sonarqube](http://www.sonarqube.org/)

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the log level in a catch block should be error. But the level of log: error, warn or info is not related to the location of it in code (catch block), but the relevance of the information.

I think the use of exceptions may be misused in your project. But it is difficult to judge without knowing the context ...